# Proof of the Iteration Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

The author give a definition of the set $K$ used in the proof and four steps to do the proof.

The question is stated as:

A Proof about the Iteration Theorem. Consider a set $W$, an element $c$, and a singulary operation $g$ on $W$. Let $(P,S,1)$ be a Peano system. We must show that there is a unique function $F:P\rightarrow W$ such that $F(1)=c$ and $F(S(x)=g(F(x))$ for all $x$ in $P$.

Let $K = \{ H:H \subseteq P\times W \land (1,c) \in H \land (\forall x)(\forall w)((x,w) \in H \Rightarrow (S(x), g(w)) \in H\}$.

Observe that $P \times W \in K$.

Let $F = \bigcap_{H \in K}H$

Prove:

a. $F \in K$

b. $F:P \rightarrow W$. (Hint: Let $B = \{x : (\exists!w)(w \in W \land (x,w) \in F) \}$. By mathematical induction prove B=P.)

c. $F(1) = c$.

d. $F(S(x)) = g(F(x))$ for all $x$ in $P$.

My atempt:

a)

- By definition of $F$ we have that $(\forall x)(\forall y)((x,y) \in F \Rightarrow (\forall H)(H \in K \Rightarrow (x,y) \in H))$, Thus $(\forall H)(H \in K \Rightarrow F \subseteq H)$ and as $(\forall H)(H \in K \Rightarrow H \subseteq P \times W)$ we have also $F \subseteq P \times W$
- As for all $H$ in $K$ we have $(1,c) \in H$, then $ (1,c) \in \bigcap_{H \in K}H$ and therefore $(1,c) \in F$.
- Let $(x,y)$ be some arbitrary element of $F$, the by defintition it belongs to every $H$ in $K$, thus by definition of $K$, $(S(x), g(y))$ belong to every $H$ in $K$ and therefore belongs to $F$ also, as $(x,y)$ is arbitrary we got $(\forall x)(\forall y)((x,y) \in F \Rightarrow (S(x), g(y)) \in F)$.

Thus we have that $F$ met all conditions to belong to $K$ and therefore $F \in K$.

b) (Using the set $B$ defined in the hint above)

- First let some $N \in K$ where $(\forall y)((1,y) \in N \Rightarrow y=c)$, from this we have that $(\forall y)((1,y) \in \bigcap_{H \in K}H) \Rightarrow y=c$, thus by definition of $F$ we have that $(\exists !w)(w \in W \land (1,w) \in F)$, namely $w=c$, therefore $1 \in B$.
- Now assume $x \in B$ thus $(\exists !w)(w \in W \land (x,w) \in F)$, by definition of $F$ we have that $(x,w)$ belong to every $H$ in $K$, thus by definition of $K$ we got that $(S(x), g(w))$ belong to every $H$ in $K$ and therefore $(S(x), g(w)) \in F$.
- Let some $M$ in $K$ be defined with the following restriction $(\forall y)((S(x),y) \in M \Rightarrow y = g(w))$, thus $(\forall y)((S(x),y) \in \bigcap_{H \in K}H \Rightarrow y=g(w))$, from this and by definition of $F$ we have that $(\exists !u)(u \in W \land (S(x), u) \in F)$, namely $u=g(w)$, therefore we have shown that $x \in B \Rightarrow S(x) \in B$, thus by Mathematical induction $B=P$.

c)

We have $(1,y) \in F$, then $(1,y)$ belong to every $H$ in $K$. Let some $O$ in $K$ where $(\forall y)((1,y) \in O \Rightarrow y=c)$, then $(\forall y)((1,y) \in \bigcap_{H \in K}H \Rightarrow y=c)$, thus by definition of $F$ we have that $F(1) = c$.

d)

- Let $A = \{x : x \in P \land F(S(x)) = g(F(x))\}$.

First $(1,c) \in F \Rightarrow (\forall H)(H \in K \Rightarrow (1,c) \in H)$, thus $(S(1), g(c))$ belong to every $H$ in $K$ and from this $F(S(1)) = g(F(1)) = g(c)$, thus $1 \in A$.

- Now assume $x \in A$, thus $x \in P \land F(S(x)) = g(F(x))$, as $(S(x), g(F(x)) \in F$, then $(S(x), g(F(x))$ belong to every $H$ in $K$, therefore (S(S(x)), g(g(F(x)))) belong to every $H$ in $K$ thus we got that $F(S(S(x))) = (g(F(S(x)))$, thus $S(x) \in A$. We have shown that $x \in A \Rightarrow S(x) \in A$, then by Mathematical induction A=P.